# Drawing an irregular circle with an array of points

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm trying to draw an irregular circles that animates for the first n number of frames in a sketch. What I want is to generate points and then to draw a line from the current point to the previous one, but am getting an error.

```
function irregularCircle(limit) {
  let points = []
  let t = frameCount / 20
  let i = floor(t)
  if (frameCount < limit) {
    let radius = w(.25)
    let x = width/2 + radius*cos(t)*noise(t/2)
    let y = height/2 + radius*sin(t)*noise(t/2)
    let point = createVector(x,y)
    points.push(point)
    let pt = points[i]
    let old_pt = points[i-1]
    stroke(24,34,64,75)
    strokeWeight(w(.001))
    if (frameCount > 1 && frameCount < limit) {
      line(pt.x,pt.y,old_pt.x,old_pt.y)
    }
  }
}
```

I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'x')" in response. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: no longer getting the error, but still not drawing a circle.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: These look like typos: `point[i]` and `point[i-1]`. Shouldn't they be `points[i]` and `points[i-1]`?

Comment: Thank you, should've caught that! But I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: If `point = createVector(x,y)` and `pt = point[i]`, what is `pt.x` ?  I think you must mean to assign pt to some member of the `points` array (plural, not `point`), but be careful with that array index, `i`! It appears very loosely associated with the array length

Comment: Yes, @AntonE you need to make sure both `i` and `i -1` are valid indices in the `points` array.

Comment: Edited so that now I'm not getting an error, but it's not drawing the circle either. What I was trying to do was get a coordinate several times a second and add them to the array - how would I do this effectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@danh si right about `i-1`.

Additionally there another error:
`let points = [];` should probably be global, otherwise the list gets reset with each call.

It's unclear what the `w()` function does, but you should double check the values returned are valid.

Here's a tweaked version of your code with the above notes applied:

```js
let points = [];
  
function setup() {
  createCanvas(300, 300);
}

function draw() {
  irregularCircle(3200);
}

function irregularCircle(limit) {
  let t = frameCount / 20
  let i = floor(t)
  if (frameCount < limit) {
    let radius = 250;
    let x = width/2 + radius*cos(t)*noise(t/2)
    let y = height/2 + radius*sin(t)*noise(t/2)
    let point = createVector(x,y)
    points.push(point)
    let pt = points[i]
    let old_pt = points[i > 0 ? i-1 : 0]
    stroke(24,34,64,75)
    strokeWeight(0.1);
    if (frameCount > 1 && frameCount < limit) {
      line(pt.x,pt.y,old_pt.x,old_pt.y)
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Since you're connecting the previous point to the current point, you might not need to keep appending points to a list: you can simply hold a reference to the previous point instead:

```js
let oldPt;
  
function setup() {
  createCanvas(300, 300);
}

function draw() {
  irregularCircle(3200);
}

function irregularCircle(limit) {
  let t = frameCount / 20
  let i = floor(t)
  if (frameCount < limit) {
    let radius = 250;
    let x = width/2 + radius*cos(t)*noise(t/2)
    let y = height/2 + radius*sin(t)*noise(t/2)
    let pt = createVector(x,y)
    // check if the previous point exists before drawing a line
    if(oldPt){
      if (frameCount > 1 && frameCount < limit) {
        line(pt.x,pt.y,oldPt.x,oldPt.y)
      }
    }
    // now that we've drawn the line we can point the old point to the current point
    oldPt = pt;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Brilliant, this does exactly as intended. Thank you!

Comment: Marked as correct, however, I can't upvote as I'm too new to stackoverflow; will do once it lets me. I did have a follow-up question though: making either the array or the oldPt global variables is an issue for me as I want to be able to draw n number of circles, hence my initial approach where I had the array inside the function. Any suggestions on how to set this up so cleanly/efficiently? Thanks again!